# Was Blaster from "Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome" the same character as the big farmhand from "Mad Max"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, mad-max, mad-max-3

In the movie "Mad Max", there was a large farmhand character. In the "Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome" movie, Max fights a masked giant in the dome. I have always imagined it was the same character (big farmboy) from "Mad Max" that had managed to survive the apocolypse by way of his brawn (as "Blaster"). When Max unmasks him, Blaster smiles a "No hard feelings" smile at Max. Is Blaster in "Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome" supposed to be the same character as the farmhand in "Mad Max"?

Comment: [Also posted on Science Fiction & Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9568/was-blaster-in-mad-max-beyond-thunderdome-supposed-to-be-the-big-farmhand-in-the)

Answer (score 8):

While this sounds like an awesome theory, I'd have to go with "No, they are not."

The farmhand, when Max met him, was an older man, looking well into his early 60s. Judging from Blaster's physique in Thunderdome and given that the third film takes place [15 years after the farmhand scene from the original Mad Max](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Max_Beyond_Thunderdome#Plot), the farmhand would have been well into his 70s by that point. Regardless of how in shape you are, at that age your skin isn't going to look like a glistening professional wrestler. Especially in a dystopian environment like in the Mad Max films.

I always attributed that look to Blaster's perceived lack of intelligence, yet understanding of "this is how the world works."

Comment: Web sleuthing isn't bringing up any Mad Max farmhand pics. Looks like it may be time for me to rent the movie. The MM character I'm asking about was in his teens or early twenties wearing overalls and carrying a shotgun and young enough to be Blaster fifteen years later. You may be thinking of the old ladies husband?

Comment: Here is a link referencing this question, but not exactly answering it: http://www.madmaxmovies.com/flubs/othertrivia.html

Comment: Ah, I was! My apologies. Looks like I def need to revisit the movie too! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to state that the farmhand and Blaster were the same person. Both seemed to have Down's Syndrome or a similar condition. I think the farmhand may well be May's son and if May was Jessie's aunt, so Max may well identify with Blaster as similar to the man in the first movie who may well be his wife's first cousin.